# Getting 403 Forbidden code when using .htaccess in wamp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

I'm trying to use my API by using `.htaccess` file (using WAMP and windows 10). I get a

> 403 Forbidden

error.

My `.htaccess` file located in `c/wamp/www/work`:

```
    Options -Indexes

#Set the response headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    #Enable the Rewrite Engine
    RewriteEngine On

    #Rewrite the base to /work
    RewriteBase /work

    #If the request if not for the receiver - redirect to the api server
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api\index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

and to my `httpd.conf` file I added the following

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

but I still getting a `403 Forbidden` error. I know the `.htaccess` file works.

also in my `http://localhost/work/` **i can see all the folders** except api folder

Comment: What are those double asterisks for in your server config? (An attempt at styling?)

Comment: You have a backslash in your `RewriteRule` substitution, rather than a (forward) slash - although this should result in a 404, not a 403. Can you give an example of the requested URL please.

Comment: i fixed that but still i get 403. example of the URL requested: `http://localhost/work/api/index.php?campaigns` and i get : `You don't have permission to access /work/api/index.php on this server.`

Comment: Can you access any file? If you remove .htaccess can you access anything?

Comment: Problem solved. i had 2 htacess files. i delete one and now its ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> example of the URL requested: `localhost/work/api/index.php?campaigns`

That URL doesn't make much sense given the directives in your .htaccess file, as it would be rewritten to:

```
/work/api/index.php?request=index.php&campaigns
```

From that I would guess that it was your API that was generating the 403?

The directive in your .htaccess file looks like it is expecting something like: `localhost/work/api/campaigns`?

Comment: i cant access to the files that in the api folder. the requested is ok for sure. even if i try just to reach the `http://localhost/work/api/` i get 403 Forbidden